# Is there any Visual Studio extension to switch to related files?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-extensions

Suppose an architecture where a certain functionality - a "component" - is scattered across many related files. For example there is a HTML template, a JavaScript file, a CSS file etc. belonging together. Should be common in any non-trivial project.

The more technical layers are used, the more you need to switch between related files. In a current project I have 6 layers that need to be edited for one functionality. Since the files are grouped by technical layers, they are not near each other. Which makes the trivial task of switching files time-consuming.

Is there any known Visual Studio extension which does help with that situation?

For designers (WinForms/WPF/...) a similiar feature always existed (go to designer, go to code).

Just an idea how it could look like:

[image: Wireframe1]

Having it in the context menu would be OK as well.
Maybe I am lucky and it already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between related files with my (commercial) [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension if they have a common part in the file name. On how to create custom title and path rules see [Tab Grouping](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/visual_studio_tab_grouping.html) documentation.

Comment: It definitely does link related files, so I accept this answer